How do i solve ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiogram.middlewares'?
import sqlite3
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext
from aiogram.filters import Command
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, CallbackQuery
from aiogram.middlewares.logging import LoggingMiddleware
from aiogram.fsm.storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from datetime import datetime

under 'from aiogram.middlewares.logging import LoggingMiddleware' the errors comes from here
finding an alternative ways

What version?  In older versions, it was aiogram.dispatcher.middlewares.
